# Salesforce Import Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am having issue with marketing cloud import activity.

I am trying to do below things -

Go to Marketing Cloud --> Email Studio --> Interaction --> Import

Select report from sales cloud and add the name and save config so when i am saving the data it gives me an error -

> "Import Definition Validation Error User does not have access to
>   Salesforce objects or reports."

And new data extension is created but with 0 record count.

Is there something i am doing wrong ?

And when i am trying to import record into Data Extension record count still can't increase.

- Using 18 digit id
- Added Contact ID and Account ID into report
- Contact ID is primary key while importing data

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Check for two things.

1) The integration user (used to authenticate between Clouds) and your own user Marketing Cloud are both set as **Integrated** in the [user options](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_manage_users.htm&type=5).

2) The report you are trying to import isn't stored in your or someone else's personal Reports folder in Sales Cloud.